# Loop infinito ao recuperar e gravar dados no Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, mobile

sou iniciante em Android e tive um problema ao recuperar um dado do Firebase e gravar novamente, sei o motivo do loop infinito mas não sei como corrigir.

```
public static void setVoto (String candidato){
    votoFirebase = referenciaDatabase.child(candidato).child("votos");



    votoFirebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            voto = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                votoInt = Integer.parseInt(voto);
                votoFirebase.setValue(votoInt + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

O problema acontece que sempre que é alterado o valor, ele volta para o método, então quando a pessoa vota, ele fica em um loop infinito..
Como eu posso corrigir, ou usar outra função para que eu possa recuperar a pontuação atual no firebase e possa gravar o dado somando +1 sem que ocorra o loop ? 
Eu tentei criar uma flag, funcionou, porem quando o app é fechado e aberto, a flag volta como true e permite que o usuario vote novamente...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está utilizando um `ValueEventListener`. Ele é chamado sempre que acontece uma alteração na Database. Isso significa que sempre que você incrementa o número de votos, ele é chamado novamente e incrementa mais uma vez.

Para resolver isso, utilize um `ListenerForSingleValueEvent`:

```
votoFirebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        voto = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        votoInt = Integer.parseInt(voto);
        votoFirebase.setValue(votoInt + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou